# Should I use cut or awk to extract fields and field substrings?

Tags: sed, awk, field, cut, text-parsing

I have a file with pipe-separated fields. I want to print a subset of field 1 and all of field 2:

`cat tmpfile.txt`

```
# 10 chars.|variable length num|text
ABCDEFGHIJ|99|U|HOMEWORK
JIDVESDFXW|8|C|CHORES
DDFEXFEWEW|73|B|AFTER-HOURS
```

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
# 6 chars.|variable length num
ABCDEF|99
JIDVES|8
DDFEXF|73
```

I know how to get fields 1 & 2:

```
cat tmpfile.txt | awk '{FS="|"} {print $1"|"$2}'
```

And know how to get the first 6 characters of field 1:

```
cat tmpfile.txt | cut -c 1-6
```

I know this is fairly simple, but I can't figure out is how to combine the `awk` and `cut` commands.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

You could use `awk`.  Use the [`substr()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to trim the first field:

```
awk -F'|' '{print substr($1,1,6),$2}' OFS='|' inputfile
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
ABCDEF|99
JIDVES|8
DDFEXF|73
```

---

Using `sed`, you could say:

```
sed -r 's/^(.{6})[^|]*([|][^|]*).*/\1\2/' inputfile
```

to produce the same output.

Comment: +1; slightly shorter: `awk -F'|' '{print substr($1,1,6) FS $2}' inputfile`

Comment: If shortness is important: `awk -F\| '{$0=substr($1,1,6)FS$2}1'`

Comment: Thank you -What does the "1" (not the $1) mean in this context?

Comment: @user3486154 You can consider it equivalent to `print`.

Comment: @user3486154 Its a very basic thing in `awk`, its the same as `1 {print $0}`.  It just print the current line.  Or do you mean the `1` in `substr`? Start at position `1` of the string.

Comment: @Jotne Why even bother the braces and `1`. `awk -F\| '$0=substr($1,1,6)FS$2'` should suffice. `;)`

Comment: @jaypal Clever :)  Just this will always be true hence printed.

Comment: Good one! I sometimes find more clear to use `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` when both FS/OFS are the same.

Comment: @fedorqui You're perhaps right in the sense that it's more clear.  I find it cumbersome to add a `BEGIN` block and those curly parenthesis that demand pressing the Shift key.  It hurts, ouch!

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use cut and paste, but then you have to read the file twice, which is a big deal if the file is very large:

```
paste -d '|' <(cut -c 1-6 tmpfile.txt ) <(cut -d '|' -f2 tmpfile.txt )
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for another variation: `awk -F\| -vOFS=\| '{print $1,$2}' t.in | cut -c 1-6,11-`

Also, as tripleee points out, two cuts can do this too: `cut -c 1-6,11- t.in | cut -d\| -f 1,2`

Comment: Or if you can guesstimate the maximal length of the second field, use two cuts; `cut -c1-6,11-16 t.in | cut -d'|' -f1-2`

Answer (score 1):

I like a combination of cut and sed, but that's just a preference:

```
cut -f1-2 -d"|" tmpfile.txt|sed 's/\([A-Z]\{6\}\)[A-Z]\{4\}/\1/g'
```

Result:

```
# 10-digits|variable length num
ABCDEF|99
JIDVES|8
DDFEXF|73
```

Edit: (Removed the useless cat)  Thanks!